# MySQL: JOIN and WHERE with multiple matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to select products from `products` table with the attributes with id 2 and 5 using the following query:

```
SELECT `products`.`title`, `products`.`price` 
FROM `products` 
LEFT JOIN `products_attributes_mapping` 
    ON `products`.`id` = `products_attributes_mapping`.`product_id` 
WHERE 
    `products_attributes_mapping`.`attribute_value_id` IN (2) 
    AND `products_attributes_mapping`.`attribute_value_id` IN (5) 
GROUP BY `products`.`id`
```

I expect the product `'Example product 1, blue, size 1'` to be returned. But I don't get any result, even though the product with id 1 has `attribute_value_id` 2 and 5 assigned in the `products_attributes_mapping` table.

I use `IN` because I would like to be able to provide multiple attributes, I simplified it only for the example.

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fd94f2/1/0

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    `price` double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `products_attributes` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `products_attributes_mapping` (
    `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `attribute_value_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `products_attributes_values` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `attribute_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Data

```
INSERT INTO `products` VALUES 
    (1,'Example product 1, blue, size 1',10),
    (2,'Example product 2, yellow, size 1',10),
    (3,'Example product 3, black, size 2',15),
    (4,'Example product 4, red, size 2',15);

INSERT INTO `products_attributes` VALUES 
    (1,'Color'),
    (2,'Size');

INSERT INTO `products_attributes_mapping` VALUES 
    (1,2),
    (1,5),
    (2,4),
    (2,5),
    (3,3),
    (3,6),
    (4,1),
    (4,6);

INSERT INTO `products_attributes_values` VALUES 
    (1,1,'red'),
    (2,1,'blue'),
    (3,1,'black'),
    (4,1,'yellow'),
    (5,2,'1'),
    (6,2,'2'),
    (7,2,'3'),
    (8,2,'4');
```

Comment: One .. You don't need the `AND` statment: `AND products_attributes_mapping.attribute_value_id IN (5)` because you're using `IN` ..   On the original `WHERE` just use: `attribute_value_id IN (2,5)`

Comment: Your `WHERE` has you trying to select a record that has an `attribute_value_id` of both 2 & 5.

Comment: How would `products_attributes_mapping.attribute_value_id IN (2) 
    AND products_attributes_mapping.attribute_value_id IN (5)` ever return any result?  `attribute_value_id` can't be both 2 and 5 at the same time.

Comment: @ItsPete @Eric That's what I want. I would like to get the product which have in `products_attributes_mapping` assigned `attribute_value_id` 2 and 5 at the same time. And there are the corresponding entries: `INSERT INTO products_attributes_mapping VALUES (1,2) (1,5);`

Comment: @Zak That would result in an "or": I would get all products with `attribute_value_id`  2 OR 5. Not the product(s) with `attribute_value_id`  2 AND 5.

Comment: @Hativ The problem with your current query is that it for this query to produce any results, a single record in `products_attributes_mapping` must be both 2 & 5. Since it is only ever one value at a time, no results are returned. GMB's solution below will allow you to specify that products require multiple attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using aggregation could indeed be a solution. You can use a `HAVING` clause to ensure that a products has certain attribute values:

```
SELECT p.title, p.price
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_attributes_mapping pm ON p.id = pm.product_id 
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.price
HAVING 
    MAX(pm.attribute_value_id = 2) = 1
    AND MAX(pm.attribute_value_id = 5) = 1
```

In **[your DB fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2fd94f2/18)**, this query returns:

```
title                            | price
---------------------------------|-------
Example product 1, blue, size 1  | 10
```

You can easily extend the expression by adding more `AND MAX(...) = 1` conditions.

Another option would be to use a series of `WHERE EXISTS` conditions with correlated subqueries to search the attributes tables. This is just as good, but will expand as a longer query if you need to add many conditions.